# How did the Mosasaurus survive that long?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

If (numerous) online sources are to be believed, the events of *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom* occur 3 years after the events of *Jurassic World*.  Is there any explanation (in- or out-of-universe) as to how the mosasaurus survived that long?  Clearly it wasn't being fed.  Was there some other food source?  Or is there some indication that its escape scene (the "salvage vessel" opening scene of *Kingdom*) occurred closer to the end of the *World*, while the rest of *Kingdom* did not happen until much later?

Comment: It's possible that she had some food in her encloser. Weren't there fishes in her water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**According to**](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2445219/when-jurassic-world-fallen-kingdoms-opening-scene-actually-takes-place) producer and co-writer **[Colin Trevorrow](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1119880/)** the opening scene takes place about a month after **Jurassic World**:

> **The opening sequence is set just after [Jurassic World]**. There's 3
>   years that pass. We didn't put that type up onto the screen, but **the
>   opening sequence could even be weeks after, or a month after**, and then
>   time passes to allow them to create [the Indoraptor].

*(this however makes me wonder why the team tasked with retrieving the Indominus Rex DNA were so sure that the dinosaurs were dead, especially since Claire's Dinosaur Protection Group seemingly worked hard to keep them alive)*

Answer (score 3):

This [**question on SF&F**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189378/how-did-the-mosasaurus-stay-alive) has at least a partial explanation

> In the film Jurassic World we see the mosasaurus jump out of the water to catch a pteranodon as well as beaching itself to catch the i-Rex™.
>
> Presumably it can simply keep doing that whenever it gets hungry. There's apparently no shortage of dinos (both flying and non) left on the island at the end of the film.

Indeed, the Mosasaurus was *trained* to eat that way as demonstrated in *Jurassic World*

[image]

It continues to do so, by attacking the technician dangling from the helicopter

[image]

However, what is, perhaps, also relevant is that the enclosure / home of the Mosasaur is **enormous**....

[image]

[image]

.... so it's entirely possible that this habitat has sufficient renewable resources to continue to feed the Mosasaur. Although there is a *giant* gate to hold the Mosasaur in, it's quite possible that there are much smaller gates / openings to allow for water flow and / or other aquatic life to enter the habitat.

Indeed, water renewal would be a must since it would get pretty funky after 3 years.

Comment: Hmm, even if smaller aquatic life could easily enter the "tank", it seems like a huge stretch to think it would be enough.  A humpback whale—roughly the same size—eats ~5000 lbs. of food per day.  I have a hard time believing the mosasaurus would have access to that much *daily*.  Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: We don't know the eating habits of the dinosaur....you asked for a possible explanation and I gave you two.

Comment: Sorry, not meaning to sound ungrateful.  Just thinking out loud.  Not sure if I can suspend my disbelief that much.

Comment: So you can believe in giant dinosaurs attacking helicopters but not their feeding habits... ☺☺

Comment: Oddly enough the official park map that was released for __Jurassic World__ showed the lagoon __[in the center of the island](http://islanublar.jurassicworld.com/park-map/)__, in __Fallen Kingdom__ however it seemed to be right next to the ocean.

Comment: @Oliver_C:  Good find!

Comment: The Jurassic World website has been updated to reflect the closing due to volcanic activity and that it is preserved by the Dinosaur Conservation Group!  Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

One thing many people tend to forget is the mosasaur is an aquatic reptile. It has been proven that large snakes and crocodilians can go a year or more without food. Most reptiles can enter a type of hibernation and as long as they have air there's no reason to think a mosasaur couldn't do the same. So with the occasional stupid dinosaur or flying reptile there's plenty to explain why she's still alive all be it extremely hungry.